# Print to console while printing to pdf in R

Tags: r

I am trying to print many plots to a PDF-file in R. The thing is, that there are more than 3k plots to print and I want to know, what plot is being processed now. My code looks like this:

```
pdf("plots.pdf", onefile = TRUE)

for(i in 1:columns_amount) {
    for(j in (i + 1):columns_amount) {
        print(ggplot(...))
    }
}

dev.off()
```

The `print()`-method in this case prints the plot to the PDF-file. But I want to add something to print `i` and `j` values to console, so it looks like:

```
for(i in 1:columns_amount) {
    for(j in (i + 1):columns_amount) {
        print(ggplot(...))
        print_to_console(i, j)
    }
}
```

Are there any possibilities to do that? I just want to know, which stage the program is on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `print` try using `message` and/or `cat`. Like this:

```
message("This is a message")
cat(i,j)
```

Comment: Thanks! This helped!

Comment: I'm glad it helped! If this is what you needed, please, don't forget to accept the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

The sprintf() function returns a formatted string, the print() induces the side effect you're looking for.

```
for(i in 1:3){
      for(j in 1:3){
            print(sprintf("Processing i=%s j=%s", i, j))
      }
}

[1] "Processing i=1 j=1"
[1] "Processing i=1 j=2"
[1] "Processing i=1 j=3"
[1] "Processing i=2 j=1"
[1] "Processing i=2 j=2"
[1] "Processing i=2 j=3"
[1] "Processing i=3 j=1"
[1] "Processing i=3 j=2"
[1] "Processing i=3 j=3"
```

Answer (score 0):

Another potential solution is to create a function that does the plotting and lapply it to your columns. This example shows how to plot each of the "Value" columns, 1 per page in a PDF, using the corresponding column name as the plot title. You need to use `ensym()` and the bang bang operator (`!!` e.g. https://www.r-bloggers.com/2019/07/bang-bang-how-to-program-with-dplyr/) to specify when to use the column name (as a string, eg "Value1") and when to use the values in column, but I've found it to be the best solution in my work (thousands of plots per pdf which can be searched by column name, e.g. `ctrl+f Value2`).

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggrepel)

plot_data <- function(ValueX) {
  ValueX <- ensym(ValueX)
  ggplot(df, aes(y = !!ValueX,
                   x = Name)) +
    geom_text_repel(aes(label =  ifelse(!!ValueX < 0,
                        Name, NA))) +
    geom_point() +
    theme_bw(base_family = "Helvetica", base_size = 14) +
    ggtitle(ValueX) +
    theme(axis.ticks.x = element_blank(),
          legend.position = "none")
}

df <- readr::read_table("  Name      Value1     Value2     Value3
1   A1 -0.05970872 -1.1651404  1.3516952
2   A2  0.44143488 -0.7270722 -1.9870423
3   A3  0.34616897 -0.3891095  0.9123736
4   A4  0.49289331  1.3957877 -0.2689896
5   A5 -1.39354557  0.9429327  1.0719274") %>% 
  select(-c(X1))

## Collate colnames into a vector
vector_of_colnames <- colnames(df)[-1]

pdf(file=paste0("Project_X_plots.pdf"))
lapply(vector_of_colnames, plot_data)
dev.off()

# The console output counts the number of plots as they are loaded into the pdf
#>[[1]]
#>
#>[[2]]
#>
#>[[3]]
```